# SendGrid API: Get Campaign Stats

Tags: php, sendgrid-api-v3

I've been looking for a way to get SendGrid stats for specific campaigns. I can see the stats on the Campaigns page of the SendGrid dashboard, but I can't find an API endpoint to get that data.

I could retrieve the Global and Overview stats, no problem, but in this case, those are not helpful for me. I need *per-campaign* stats. Is there a way to get those reports through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my situation by creating unique (ID-like) categories for each campaign. This way, I can use the [Category Stats API Endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Stats/categories.html). It's not a semantically correct usage of categories, but this is the only way I found to achieve this.

#### Update July 2017:

I also achieved this goal + much more by using [SendGrid Subusers](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/subusers.html) and the [`on-behalf-of: subuser_<username>` header](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html) (search `on behalf of subuser` in the left searchbox). This header allows you to create requests using the parent account on behalf the subuser.

Comment: But, how to create a campaign through the v3 API? There seems to be a GET only...

Comment: @neoMagic You can use the same endpoint (`/v3/campaigns`) to create a campaign by sending a POST. Here is the documentation for the parameters that you can send: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/campaigns.html#Create-a-Campaign-POST

Comment: Thanks but I meant `category` instead of `campaign`... but there seems to be an option to create a `category` while creating a `campaign`... so problem solved and either way, your answer was useful ;-)

Comment: Isnt it strange that Sendgrid hasnt provided a campaign statistics API! Is sendgrid tyring to make it tougher for developers?

Answer (score 2):

Campaign level stats are not available via the official Sendgrid API, at least not that I could find.

However, there are a couple of undocumented URLs you can use to get campaign level stats:

https://sendgrid.com/marketing_campaigns/campaigns/CAMPAIGN_ID/stats.csv

^ this returns data in CSV format

https://sendgrid.com/marketing_campaigns/campaigns/CAMPAIGN_ID/stats.json

^ this returns data in JSON format

Note that these are the endpoints used by the Sendgrid web client, and so require authentication via Cookie token.

To obtain a token you can use the https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/public/tokens endpoint, and send your `username` and `password` in the payload.

Then you can send that token as a Cookie along with your requests to the above Sendgrid web client endpoints. Note, you must use cookie name `mako_auth_token`.

Comment: Also, to get link Campaign link stats, you can use: https://sendgrid.com/marketing_campaigns/campaigns/CAMPAIGN_ID/stats/0/links-current.json